# #include other C programs

Tags: c, include

I need to include file_1.c into main.c. In file_1.c, I currently have multiple functions. If I want to call these functions in main.c, what do I need to do? I have #include"file_1.c" in my main program.

Comment: *"I need to include file_1.c into main.c"* No, you don't. That's what *[linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))* is for.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. I just feel like I don't understand completely what's going on with #include. Basically, I want functions from another C program to be called in my main program.

Comment: I know what #include is for. I'm just at a point in my C learning where I need to include other functions in my main program to be able to merge everything together.

Comment: @iHubble, you are at an important point in learning C.  If you choose to use #include include a .c file, you will put yourself back about 3 years.  Do not do it!!  Use the linker to access functions in another translation unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use standard approach by making header file

`#include"file_1.h"`

you will have to compile this `"file_1.c"` together with `main.c` and make one executable 
because function calls are need in run time.

Try this :

create a header file `file_1.h`

```
#ifndef _FILE_H
#define _FILE_H

void foo(int );
#endif
```

give all the declaraion of function and struct definitions (if any) or any global variables

then in `file_1.c` will contain actual defintion of function

```
//file_1.c

    #include "file_1.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    void foo(int x)
    {
      printf("%d\t",x);
    }

//main.c
    #include "file_1.h"

    int main()
    {
    int x=10;
    foo(x);
    return 0;
    }
```

include header file `file_1.h` in both (`main.c` and `file_1.c`) the `c` files

In `gcc`

`gcc -Wall main.c file_1.c -o myexe.out`

Comment: You *can*, you just don't want to.

Comment: May I ask what "_FILE_H" means?

Comment: It's just a preprocessing guard used to define some name so that in final exe only one header is included , means if not defined NAME then define one and include all otherwise this guard will check and if already defined then won't include it again

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explaining all this trivial stuff to me instead of asking me if I read a C book. This is highly useful.

Comment: @iHubble: also you can give any name you want .. but meaningful name is desireable

Comment: @iHubble: If you satisfied then you can accept the answer as well

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think you need to do this?

Normally you would add the declaration of functions in file_1.c into file_1.h and include that in main.c.

When you link the program, you just need to include both main.c and file_1.c (which then includes the definitions of the functions) on the command line.